# How to Upload Files to the server and store in inside the public folder of Nuxt? Not working in production

Tags: vercel, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nitro

I am trying to upload files using an API and then store them inside the public folder of Nuxt.

This code works but is not in production.

`~/server/api/upload.post.ts`

```js
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

export default defineEventHandler(async(event) => {
  const files = await readMultipartFormData(event)

  const uploadedFilePaths:string[] = []

  files?.forEach((file) => {
    const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public', file.filename as string)
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, file.data)
    uploadedFilePaths.push(`/${file.filename}`)
  })
  return uploadedFilePaths
})
```

So, I think `fs` and `path` from `node` won't work because the file directory will change in production.

I tried using the `useStorage` from Nitro but it still doesn't work.

Here is my configuration

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: true,
  nitro: {
    storage: {
      fs: {
        driver: 'fs',
        base: './public'
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Then the `~/server/api/upload.post.ts`

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const files = await readMultipartFormData(event)
  const uploadFilePaths:string[] = []
  files?.forEach((file) => {
    useStorage().setItemRaw(`fs:${file.filename}`, file.data)
    uploadFilePaths.push(`${getRequestURL(event).origin}/${file.filename}`)
  }) 
  return uploadFilePaths
});
```

so when I upload the file in production, it returns the file paths but when I view the uploaded file I get 404 not found.

Comment: Can you please add more details about what your production environment is? Knowing what you're using to deploy this code would probably affect the answers given.

Comment: @NikoChaffin,  I am unsure what you mean by production environment. I am not using any environment, my projects are deployed in Vercel.

Comment: That's what I meant: where your projects were being deployed.

Answer (score 3):

I see:

```bash
+----------------------+                +----------------------+
|                      |                |                      |
|   Client Browser     | -- Uploads --> |   Nuxt Server (Dev)  |
|                      |                |                      |
+----------------------+                +----------+-----------+
                                                   |
                                                   | Writes to
                                                   V
                                          +----------------------+
                                          |                      |
                                          |   public/ directory  |
                                          |                      |
                                          +----------------------+
```

In development, your setup works because the file system paths are consistent and accessible.
However, in production, the file paths and permissions might differ, leading to issues.

As an alternative, you might consider, instead of writing directly to the filesystem, using a more robust solution like cloud storage (e.g., [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs)), or a dedicated file storage service. That change will make sure your file uploads work *consistently* across different environments.

Your `upload.post.ts` code (using a cloud storage solution (e.g., AWS S3)). You will need to configure the [cloud storage SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/) with your credentials and bucket details.

```js
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';

const s3 = new S3({
  /* Your AWS SDK configuration here */
});

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const files = await readMultipartFormData(event)
  const uploadFilePaths:string[] = []

  await Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: /* Your Bucket Name */,
      Key: file.filename,
      Body: file.data,
    };

    const uploadResult = await s3.upload(params).promise();
    uploadFilePaths.push(uploadResult.Location);
  }));

  return uploadFilePaths;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was hoping that there would be a way to achieve it without using Google Cloud storage.

Comment: @Reagan I agree. It is because I did not see such a way that I suggested a cloud storage.